# JQuery Cross Domain Error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf, cross-domain

The POST request

```
var url = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/MyServices.svc/GetOrders";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    crossDomain : true,
    data: 'abcd',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        data = result.data;                             
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    debugger;
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

When the url address is **localhost** i am getting a response
When trying to do so **across servers** I am getting an **Error**:

#### 405 (Method Not Allowed)

#### XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.x.x/MyServices.svc/GetOrders. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

All of the answers on the web where inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If you can deal with json in return, then try using [jsonp](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)  for speaking between domains:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  ...... etc ....
```

As documented in official site :-

> The advent of JSONP — essentially a consensual cross-site scripting
>   hack — has opened the door to powerful mashups of content. Many
>   prominent sites provide JSONP services, allowing you access to their
>   content via a predefined API.

and

> jQuery handles all the complex aspects of JSONP behind-the-scenes —
>   all we have to do is tell jQuery the name of the JSONP callback
>   parameter specified by YQL ("callback" in this case), and otherwise
>   the whole process looks and feels like a normal Ajax request.

Comment: After Changing to JsonP,
now i am not getting success or failure,

just:

send 
m.extend.ajax
anonymous function) 
event.dispatch 
r.handle